# selinux preventing PHP/Roundcube from connecting to local SMTP or IMAP ports

Tags: imap, smtp, centos-7, selinux, roundcube

**EDIT**: I've determined the cause is selinux. After disabling enforcement with `setenforce 0` everything worked. So the new question is, what's going on with selinux? I only have default CentOS 7 policies.

I've configured RoundCube mail on CentOS 7

```
<?php
  $config['db_dsnw'] = 'mysql://roundcube:redacted@localhost/webmail';
  $config['default_host'] = 'localhost';
  $config['default_port'] = 993;
  $config['smtp_server'] = 'localhost';
  $config['smtp_port'] = 587;
  $config['smtp_user'] = '%u';
  $config['smtp_pass'] = '%p';
  $config['support_url'] = '';
  $config['des_key'] = 'redacted';
  $config['plugins'] = array('archive', 'attachment_reminder', 'autologon', 'emoticons', 'filesystem_attachments', 'help', 'hide_blockquote', 'managesieve', 'markasjunk', 'newmail_notifier', 'password', 'userinfo', 'vcard_attachments', 'zipdownload');
  $config['language'] = 'en_US';
  $config['spellcheck_engine'] = 'pspell';
  $config['htmleditor'] = 2;
  $config['draft_autosave'] = 60;
  $config['preview_pane'] = true;
```

and when testing SMPT, I get the error:

```
Trying to send email...
SMTP send:  NOT OK(Connection failed: Failed to connect socket: Permission denied)
```

and with IMAP:

```
Connecting to localhost...
IMAP connect:  NOT OK(Login failed for user from my.ip.ad.dr Could not connect to localhost:993: Permission denied)
```

But... the ports are fine. They're open. I've verified this:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:993 -crlf
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify return:1
...
$ openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:587 -starttls smtp
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify return:1
...
$ openssl s_client -connect [::1]:993 -crlf
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify return:1
...
$ openssl s_client -connect [::1]:587 -starttls smtp
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify return:1
...
```

`iptables` is not installed, `firewalld` is used in its place.

I've taken down `firewalld` for testing.

Any idea what's going on here?

```
$ uname -a
Linux gbox 3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Aug 14 21:49:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)`
$ httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Jun 27 2018 13:48:59
$ php -v
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Apr 12 2018 19:02:01)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
$ postconf -d | grep mail_version
mail_version = 2.10.1
$ dovecot --version
2.2.10
```

Comment: Localhost has two addresses. Did you verify both `[::1]` and `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: I had not, and they were not listening. However, after adding ipv6 in dovecot and postfix, I can connect via the openssl client, but not from roundcube, still. I've updated the question with the ipv6 openssl results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it was selinux. After digging deep and remembering how to read the audit log, I came up with:

`setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1`

which allows httpd to initiate socket connections (from what I understand) across the network.

Answer (score 0):

Would (probably) have worked by default if you would have used a unix domain socket instead of TCP/IP:

```
$config['db_dsnw'] = 'mysql://roundcube:redacted@unix(/run/mysqld/mysqld-roundcube.sock)/roundcubemail';
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1082793)